# How to create bigrams using dictionary in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I have a dictionary of words which I have stored in dictionary.txt file. It contains trigrams and bigrams. Now I am given a paragraph:

```
"In order to perform operations inside the abdomen, surgeons must make an incision large enough to offer adequate visibility, provide access to the abdominal organs and allow the use of hand-held surgical instruments.  These incisions may be placed in different parts of the abdominal wall.  Depending on the size of the patient and the type of operation, the incision may be 6 to 12 inches in length.  There is a significant amount of discomfort associated with these incisions that can prolong the time spent in the hospital after surgery and can limit how quickly a patient can resume normal daily activities.  Because traditional techniques have long been used and taught to generations of surgeons, they are widely available and are considered the standard treatment to which newer techniques must be compared."
```

The dictionary.txt file includes the following words:

```
hand-held surgical instruments
intensive care unit
traditional techniques
```

Now I want to create bigrams for words which is not present in the dictionary.txt.

I have used the following code in R:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
```

Can anyone help me to tell the code for the same in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your text and dictionary, I created bigrams of both, and removed the bigrams from the dictionary from the bigrams of your paragraph.

```
t <- "In order to perform operations inside the abdomen, surgeons must make an incision large enough to offer adequate visibility, provide access to the abdominal organs and allow the use of hand-held surgical instruments.  These incisions may be placed in different parts of the abdominal wall.  Depending on the size of the patient and the type of operation, the incision may be 6 to 12 inches in length.  There is a significant amount of discomfort associated with these incisions that can prolong the time spent in the hospital after surgery and can limit how quickly a patient can resume normal daily activities.  Because traditional techniques have long been used and taught to generations of surgeons, they are widely available and are considered the standard treatment to which newer techniques must be compared."


dictionary <- c("hand-held surgical instruments", "intensive care unit", "traditional techniques")

bigrams_dict <- BigramTokenizer(dictionary)
bigrams_text <- BigramTokenizer(t)

bigrams_text[!bigrams_text %in% bigrams_dict]
```

Comment: This code works!!!Thanks for the response. But I don't want to tokenize the words in the dictionary. Instead, after applying bigram, I want the words in the dictionary as such and all other words need to be tokenized

Comment: To clarify, do you want the bigrams minus the dictionary? Then there will only be one bigram removed, namely "traditional techniques". `bigrams_text[!bigrams_text %in% dictionary]`.

Comment: No, I need the output as this: "In order", "to perform", "operations inside", "surgeons must", "make an", "incision large", "enough to", "offer adequate", "visibility provide", "hand-held surgical instruments", "intensive care unit" and so on. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: I want my dictionary words as such after tokenization. These words need to be compared with the input paragraph.

Comment: If the order of the bigrams do not matter you can first remove the dictionary from the text, and then add the dictionary after you are done creating the bigrams. so use tm::removeWords(t, dictionary) first. This removes the trigrams you have in the dictionary from the text.